# Xcode 4 anything like right click to find in project?

Tags: find, xcode4

In Xcode 3, I could right click on some text in my code, select find in project, and it would.

Is there anything like that in Xcode 4, where I can search for something without typing it in?

EDIT: to clarify, my concern is to avoid having to enter whatever I am searching for.

In other words, suppose I have methods called

methodWithReallyLongNameVersionA

and

methodWithReallyLongNameVersionB

It would be nice to be able to search for the first one via a right click search, without having to copy and paste or to type the whole thing in.  This was possible in XCode 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I asked this question, the answer was "no."  However, Apple has now restored this functionality.  Right click on the text in question, then select "find selected text in workspace" from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 3):

I created a custom find scope and then used that find scope to search all within a project folder.
Create find scope as follows:

- In Navigator selector bar click the magnifying glass to bring up search navigator
- click the magnifying glass in the search text box and select 'show find options'
- clock 'Find in' list and select custom
- Create your new find scope in the dialog and set it to your project top level folder

Use this find scope in future searches.

Answer (score 2):

Command + Shift + F will search your workspace.

Comment: The simpler and most efficient answer.